# Signing merge commit with magit

Tags: magit

I know how to sign standard commits using magit, but I'm not able to sign the commits generated by merges. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add additional options to an existing popup:

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-merge-popup
  ?S "Sign using gpg" "--gpg-sign=" magit-read-gpg-secret-key)
```

This was copied straight from `magit-commit-popup`.

Also see https://github.com/magit/magit/wiki/Additional-proposed-infix-arguments-and-suffix-commands.